# When sum up 2 columns in PostgreSQL, if one record is empty, the result is empty instead of return another number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to use `select` to create a new column based on the sum of existing columns. When one of the records is empty, the return would be empty instead of the number of other columns.

For example, table_A having 2 columns as below:

```
Column_A Column_B
1        10
2
3        30
```

When I run a query:

```
Select (Column_A + Column_B) as New_Column from table_A
```

Result:

```
New_Column
11

33
```

My desired result:

```
New_Column
11
2
33
```

I searched for a while and found that Column_A + ISNULL(Column_B,0), would give me what I want.

However, it is a very simple case, I actually handle a lot of columns in which I don't know which column having empty data. Any better way instead of putting `ISNULL` before each calculation?

Comment: Using `coalesce(column_b, 0)` (or the non-standard `isnull`)  is the only option you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NULL` is the unknown. Adding anything to the unknown results in an unknown value. This is why, when you need to default to something instead of `NULL`, you can use COALESCE(yourcolumn, 0), or the even more verbose case-when syntax, like `case yourcolumn is null then 0 else yourcolumn end`.

You will need to sort this out at least once. But, to simplify your life for the case when you have to do this many times for the same `table`, you can create a `view` which would handle your desires for defaults and then `select` `from` that `view`.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use `coalesce()` across all the columns:

```
select coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) + coalesce(c, 0), . . .
```

Another method is to use a lateral `join`:

```
select t.*, x.x
from t cross join lateral
     (select sum(x) as x
      from (values (a), (b), (c), . . . ) v(x)
     ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select COALESCE(Column_A ,0) + COALESCE(Column_B,0) as New_Column from table_A
```

Will give you the desired result.